# NPE when referencing an object in a thread?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I want to use the socket object. And it seems that it is a "standard practice" for using it, or really anything internet related inside a thread.

I want to send some data over this socket with a button press, so naturally I need to reference this socket object in my onClick event handler. The socket will be constructed in a thread started in the onCreate method of the mainActivity. Here is the code:

```
package com.mypack.app.demo;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 12345;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "111.11.111.11";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {

            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
            out.println(str);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Strange enough, you'd think by the time onClick were called, socket will be instantiated. But I got the following error msgs in the logcat:

> 07-09 19:31:42.911 2243-2243/com.myapp.app.mydemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
>   07-09 19:32:31.961 2243-2243/com.myapp.app.mydemo W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.myapp.app.mydemo.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)

The specific line that error msg refers to is:

```
 new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))
```

This error is very persistent and happens whenever I click the button on the screen. Clearly for some reason "socket" object will not survive long enough till the time I press the button.

How should I fix this? Someone suggested me using some sort of synchronized block or something. I'm kind of new to java so what should I do exactly?

Comment: Well if your `onClick` fires before your Socket was intialized (which can definitely happen in a multi-threaded environment) exactly what you are perceiving right now would happen. You probably want to add an `if(socket == null)` check to prevent this.

Comment: Hi thanks Ben. I understand the merit of null checking but I just find it incredible that it should take such a long time for a socket to get initialized? If that's the case I think it's safe to assume something is holding it back in which case the null-checking doesn't really do much?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of problems with your code:

1)You can't make an OutputWriter to a socket in onClick, because you'd be writing to the socket on the main thread.  That will result in a NetworkOnMainThreadError.

2)If any exception happens in creating the socket, you'll get a NPE as the socket variable is not written

3)Socket would need to be volatile here to access it on both threads reliably. (although you shouldn't be accessing it on the main thread at all).

4)Even with it volatile, there's a race condition where the button could be clicked before the socket constructor finishes that would also allow the socket variable to be null.